# Character look ahead

Tags: java, regex-lookarounds

How would I go about making a character look-ahead method in Java? I have a text file (let's say TextFile.txt) and I need it to first read in a single character, recognise it, if it's a special character (like { = + ; etc.) return it as a token of type Y. If the character is not special (like a digit or letter), then it should look ahead to see if there is a special character or a white space, and when one does turn up, the program should then return that set of characters as a token of type X. If the program reads a digit, followed by another digit, then a letter, it should only return the two digits of type Z.

As an example, in TextFile.txt there is the following text:

```
{ test; 123test test5
test/-=test}
```

The program would read through the file, see a '{', return that token as Y, see the white space, ignore that, see the 't', because that's not a special character, look ahead and see another letter, until it reaches ';', and returns 'test' as a token of type X. The program should read '123', return that as Z, then read 'test' and return X.

I understand how the program should work, but I don't know what to use for the look ahead character reader. I looked at the Scanner class, but that doesn't have a method for nextChar() (which would have been useful).

Comment: Your requirements seem quite complicated. A few more examples might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

i think you don't really need any look ahead chars and could just read the entire text into a string and iterate over its char array. Check each char for isDigit or isLetter - if it is add to a string buffer, else flush contents of buffer into a list that holds all tokens. if the buffer is empty and the character is a digit, set a flag and flush as soon as you encounter anything except for a digit. that should do i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need one character of lookahead, I suggest using a [`PushbackReader`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html). You could also use a reader that [supports marking,](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#markSupported%28%29) but in this application I think a push-back is a easier to understand. Both of these options work when the lookahead is fixed (one character, in this case).

Simply put, you read a character from the stream and decide which token type it is (if it's whitespace, throw it away and try again). Accumulate this and subsequent characters of the token in something like a `StringBuilder`. Keep reading until you read a character that doesn't belong to that type. [Push the bad character back to the stream,](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PushbackReader.html#unread%28int%29) and return the token. The next time you request a token, the pushed-back character will be at the beginning of the stream.

Processing the stream in this way is memory-efficient, since the lookahead is fixed. The space required doesn't depend on the length of the stream (in fact, it will work with infinitely long streams).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a type of `InputStream` (Probably a `FileInputStream` in your case) and use the `read()` method to pull characters off one at a time. If those characters are not special characters/whitespace, keep them in a buffer until you find a special character/whitespace, and then return the contents of the buffer as your token of type X.

Answer (score 0):

Scanner has no `nextChar()` but you can use [`Scanner.hasNext(String)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.lang.String%29). E.g.

```
scanner.hasNext("x")
```

will test if a letter `x` is following. For more complicated lookaheads you can use [`Scanner.hasNext(Pattern)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29).

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any special lookahead functionality.  you just need to open the file as a FileReader.  then, as you process each character, if it is not a special character, you need to accumulate those characters in a separate StringBuilder until you reach a special character and can determine what the type of the current token is.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very descriptive...but I think this might give you a starting point. Split up the contents of your text file into an array of characters. Then look at each character individually and perform your test/comparison

```
char[] cArray = textToRead.toCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i < cArray.length; i++){
    //perform your logic here
}
```

iterate through each character and keep track of what you need in String or character variables.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a language parsing. I'd advise to use ANTLR. Please have a look at http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Five+minute+introduction+to+ANTLR+3